# How do I build Boost from github?

Tags: boost

I git clone boost latest source code on master branch from Github. I tried to build it but failed,

```
$ ./bootstrap.sh 
  ./bootstrap.sh: line 188: ./tools/build/src/engine/build.sh: No such file or directory
  -n Building Boost.Build engine with toolset ... 

  Failed to build Boost.Build build engine
  Consult 'bootstrap.log' for more details
```

The content of `bootstrap.log`

> 1 ./bootstrap.sh: line 218: cd: ./tools/build/src/engine: No such file or directory

---

**Question:**
I understand there is no  `./tools/build/src/engine`, how do I solve this? I also noted that

> -n Building Boost.Build engine with toolset ...

however, `bootstrap.sh` doesn't have `-n` option.

---

My develop environment:
`MacOS X10.9`  `Xcode5.1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Modular Boost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013433/how-to-install-modular-boost)

Comment: @sehe, thanks. I tried your answer on that post, I got the error " pathspec 'boost-1.55.0' did not match any file(s) known to git." And, I can build boost-1.55, however, I need to build the latest code.

Comment: This simply means that the repo you're in doesn't have the branch/tag names `boost-1.55`. Of course if you want a different branch, just ask for it, e.g.  `BOOST_VER=develop` to switch all subprojects to the `develop` branch. However, if `boost-1.55` is not a typo for `boost-1.55.0` and your clone doesn't have it, I'd suggest checking your clone (update or re-clone as required?)

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Overview

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The current documentation for building directly from the Git repo is at [Getting Started](https://github.com/boostorg/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Overview). Basically there are some additional steps to create the include directory tree and to run the build itself. NOTE, please also make sure you use the `b2` command from the cloned repo. Not whatever you might have prebuilt in your system.

Comment: thanks @GrafikRobot, I follow the link and build my latest version for boost.

Comment: How to clone specific modules and not every modules ?

Comment: @LeFlou Just don't do a recusive git clone. Then for the specific modules do: git submodule update --init "libs/whatever"

Answer (score 17):

To checkout latest version of *Boost* libraries from [GitHub](https://github.com/boostorg/) do the following:

- Checkout *Boost* super-project (only minimum required): `git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git`.
- `cd boost/`
- Checkout all the submodules (only minimum required): `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --no-fetch --depth=1`.

If an error like following occured:

```
Cloning into 'libs/predef'...
remote: Counting objects: 243, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (163/163), done.
remote: Total 243 (delta 128), reused 126 (delta 70), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (243/243), 142.82 KiB | 209.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (128/128), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'libs/predef'
```

then use script (`reget.bash`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash -vex

rm -rf $3/$1 .git/modules/$1
git clone --depth=1 --branch=$2 --single-branch --separate-git-dir .git/modules/$1 https://github.com/boostorg/$1 $3/$1
```

where `$1` is `predef`, `$2` is `master`, `$3` is `libs`, i.e. run `bash reget.bash predef master libs`.

An error can occur many times for different submodules, just use above script to clean up unrecoverable git error and to checkout latest commit for failed submodule. Then reuse `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --no-fetch --depth=1`.

After complete checking out of all the submodules, build `b2` executable. For *clang* it looks like:

```
export CC=clang
export CFLAGS="-march=native -Ofast"
export CXX=clang++
export CXXFLAGS="-march=native -Ofast"

bash bootstrap.sh --with-toolset=clang
```

You have obtained `b2` executable. Use it to build whole *Boost*:

```
sudo ./b2 -j`nproc` toolset=clang --build-dir=/tmp/build-boost --without-mpi install
```

#### ADDITIONAL:

If you want to clone only `HEAD` of *boost* itself and `HEAD`S of all the its submodules, then you may use following *Lua* script (tested on `https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git` repository):

```
-- mkdir boost ; cd boost ; lua ../git-submodules-clone-HEAD.lua https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git .
local module_url = arg[1] or 'https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git'
local module = arg[2] or module_url:match('.+/([_%d%a]+)%.git')
local branch = arg[3] or 'master'
function execute(command)
    print('# ' .. command)
    return os.execute(command)
end
-- execute('rm -rf ' .. module)
if not execute('git clone --single-branch --branch master --depth=1 ' .. module_url .. ' ' .. module) then
    io.stderr:write('can\'t clone repository from ' .. module_url .. ' to ' .. module .. '\n')
    return 1
end
-- cd $module ; git submodule update --init --recursive --remote --no-fetch --depth=1
execute('mkdir -p ' .. module .. '/.git/modules')
assert(io.input(module .. '/.gitmodules'))
local lines = {}
for line in io.lines() do
    table.insert(lines, line)
end
local submodule
local path
local submodule_url
for _, line in ipairs(lines) do
    local submodule_ = line:match('^%[submodule %"([_%d%a]-)%"%]$')
    if submodule_ then
    submodule = submodule_
    path = nil
    submodule_url = nil
    else
    local path_ = line:match('^%s*path = (.+)$')
    if path_ then
        path = path_
    else
        submodule_url = line:match('^%s*url = (.+)$')
    end
    if submodule and path and submodule_url then
        -- execute('rm -rf ' .. path)
        local git_dir = module .. '/.git/modules/' .. path:match('^.-/(.+)$')
        -- execute('rm -rf ' .. git_dir)
        execute('mkdir -p $(dirname "' .. git_dir .. '")')
        if not execute('git clone --depth=1 --single-branch --branch=' .. branch .. ' --separate-git-dir ' .. git_dir .. ' ' .. module_url .. '/' .. submodule_url .. ' ' .. module .. '/' .. path) then
            io.stderr:write('can\'t clone submodule ' .. submodule)
            return 1
        end
        path = nil
        submodule_url = nil
    end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

I really missed some important part of the documentation: `.\b2 headers`. So here follows all I've done to build `thread`, `chrono` and `date-time`, both release and debug, both static and shared, from version 1.60.0, cloning from the GitHub repo (in a Windows machine):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost
git checkout boost-1.60.0
git submodule update
bootstrap.bat
.\b2.exe headers
.\b2.exe variant=release,debug link=static,shared address-model=32 architecture=x86 --with-thread --with-chrono --with-date_time --stagedir=stage\win32 stage
.\b2.exe variant=release,debug link=static,shared address-model=64 architecture=x86 --with-thread --with-chrono --with-date_time --stagedir=stage\x64 stage
```

Don't forget the:

```
.\b2.exe headers
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The shortest answer is that, tools/build.git is missing. https://github.com/boostorg/build.git. Simply do a `git submodule update --recursive --remote` on the directory. This will download the missing tools/build and other depending directories.

Note, many more submodules would be correspondingly downloaded apart from the build submodule.