# boost mpl fold placeholder expression fails to compile

Tags: c++, boost, fold, boost-mpl

I'm trying to compile the Statemachine example from boost-mpl (located in libs/mpl/examples/fsm/player2.cpp), but it fails with boost version 1.37 and g++ 4.8.2. With boost version 1.56 and the same compiler, the build succeeds. Unfortunately, due to some platform constraints, I cannot switch to version 1.56.

I'm not expecting anyone to look into the above mentioned lengthy example, therefore I identified a minimal code snippet which illustrates the problem:

```
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using namespace mpl::placeholders;

//Basic queue datatype
template< class CURRENT, class NEXT >
struct queue_element
{
    typedef typename CURRENT::mytype mytype;
};

//type to be put at the end of the queue
struct default_queue_element
{
};

template <class TYPE>
struct wrapper{
    typedef TYPE mytype;
};

typedef mpl::vector<wrapper<int>, wrapper<char> > myvector;

//the following fold expression should create this type:
typedef queue_element<wrapper<char>, queue_element<wrapper<int>,
default_queue_element> > this_type_should_be_created;

//This typedef fails to compile with boost Version 1.37,
//but works perfectly with version 1.56
typedef typename
mpl::fold<
    myvector
    ,default_queue_element
    ,queue_element<_2,_1>
>::type
generate_queue;
```

With boost 1.37, g++ issues the following errors:

```
foldtest2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct queue_element<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<1> >’:
../boost_1_37_0/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/template_arity.hpp:85:5:   required from ‘const int boost::mpl::aux::template_arity_impl<queue_element<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<1> >, 1>::value’
../boost_1_37_0/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/template_arity.hpp:93:5:   required from ‘const int boost::mpl::aux::template_arity<queue_element<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<1> > >::value’
../boost_1_37_0/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/template_arity.hpp:98:30:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::aux::template_arity<queue_element<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<1> > >’
../boost_1_37_0/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/apply.hpp:67:8:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::apply2<queue_element<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<1> >, default_queue_element, wrapper<int> >’
../boost_1_37_0/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/fold_impl.hpp:67:85:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::aux::fold_impl<2, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<wrapper<int>, wrapper<char> >, 0l>, boost::mpl::v_iter<boost::mpl::vector<wrapper<int>, wrapper<char> >, 2l>, default_queue_element, queue_element<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<1> > >’
../boost_1_37_0/boost/mpl/fold.hpp:39:18:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::fold<boost::mpl::vector<wrapper<int>, wrapper<char> >, default_queue_element, queue_element<mpl_::arg<2>, mpl_::arg<1> > >’
foldtest2.cpp:39:6:   required from here
foldtest2.cpp:15:38: error: no type named ‘mytype’ in ‘struct mpl_::arg<2>’
     typedef typename CURRENT::mytype mytype;
```

Is there a work-around to make the code compile with boost 1.37? I have been searching the web for quite some time. If nevertheless the question has already been answered somewhere, I would be grateful if you could point that out.

Comment: Kudos for the self-contained reduction. That's pretty good. And unsurprisingly the only reason I'd ever look at an issue that's been fixed 5 years ago :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to be very simply a bug in that ancient(¹) version of boost.

A quick bisection tells me it was fixed in v1.43.0(²). [Release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_43_0.html) don't disclose the secret, but git does:

- c5621d9 MPL: merge fix for ticket #1992 [boost::mpl::zip_view does not support use as a metafunction with ::type](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1992)
- 31a2c78 MPL: merge fix for ticket #4061 [[MPL] gcc-4.5 compilation problems related to arity_helper](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4061)

It clearly appears to be the latter (confirmed by compiling against 31a2c78).

So your fix this single line in include/boost/mpl/aux_/template_arity.hpp(³):

```
sizeof(arity_helper(type_wrapper<F>(),arity_tag<N>())) - 1
```

should be

```
sizeof(::boost::mpl::aux::arity_helper(type_wrapper<F>(),arity_tag<N>())) - 1
```

***Of course the proper way to fix this is to use a supported version of boost***

---

¹ (November 3rd, 2008)!!

² (May 6th, 2010)

³ warning: also present in several copies generated in preprocessed versions of the header

Comment: Thank you so much for this hint, sehe. That solved it! Be assured that whenever I can, I rely on that latest boost version in order not to run into long-solved problems. But my embedded target unfortunately imposes some constraints.

Comment: @Daniel oh well, I can't say I fully understand (gcc seems recent enough) but anyhoops, now you know how to find these things ([start here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013433/how-to-install-modular-boost/23020818#23020818)) :)

Comment: @ sehe: Thanks for the link. And just to wrap up: Before bothering the Stack Overflow community with a question, I wanted to make sure that the issue is not specific to the TI DSP compiler. Therefore I reproduced it with a recent g++.

Comment: Ah. It makes slighly more sense now. Next time you might want to explain this in the question, as we're all professionals and we'll just go "duh, use lastest boost with gcc 4.8" :)